# App to upload images to a custom map

Tags: android, maps, geography

I am looking for an Android application which will allow me to upload an image with embedded GPS coordinates to the app and enter a title and optionally a description for the image. Then when I open the app I can click on any thumbnail of any image on the map to view it and its title and description. The GPS coordinates present in the image itself are used to place it on the map. Thanks.

(Optionally the app would allow me to view only my images or all images by everyone else as well by choosing an entry from a dropdown menu).

Comment: A bunch of them in my list [View by GeoTag](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_galleries#group_201). I've used [PhotoMap](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.bischofs.photomap) in the past, which should match everything but your optional requirement. Same goes for [EagleEye](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.bischofs.eagleeye) by the same dev. I quite liked them, good support as well.

Comment: Interesting. What's the difference between these two apps?

Comment: AFAIR *PhotoMap* only shows photos which have a GeoTag – while EagleEye shows all (and lets you apply GeoTags to photos which have none). At least that was the state about a year ago, when I've tried them and checked with the dev :)

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between the terms geotagging and GPS coordinates applied to pictures? Thanks.

Comment: No difference: GeoTagging photos means applying GPS coordinates to them (i.e. embed the coordinates in their Exif tags). // Btw: Does *EagleEye* meet your requirements? Shall I make that an answer?

Comment: I have GPS turned on in my camera but yet some puff give me "place name not yet determined" when I open them in photomap. Why???

Comment: Because your "location determination" might be too slow sometimes. If the location cannot be determined fast enough, the tagging process runs into a timeout resulting in no tag being applied. An app like [Fine Geotag](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.finegeotag) might help you with that.